# Specified Cast Not Valid - XamarinFirebase

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is my firebase database structure

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk6hF.png)

In the child, there are values , Name, Country, Age and **Uid**. The **Uid** is the focus in my question.

I am try to fetch the children of the node (Chat) based on the current logged in user.

I am basically trying to do a comparison here that, firebase should get me children who only have the `Uid = user.uid`. i.e the current logged in user. I thought `Equals()` could do the trick but i get an error with the cast.

The error points at this line `var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>().Equals(user.uid).ToString;`

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>().Equals(user.uid).ToString;
            var key = snapshot.Key;
            HashMap map;
            foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
            {

            }
```

**Console**

```
      my snapshot test: DataSnapshot { key = Chat, value = {-KomfGbZxCGESgyo1PFT={Name=Testing , Ref=7YB3mxMRXxW4lzhbhxi1bx7K4Pf1, 

   }, -KomcJyR5dCxFucJSB0I={Name=Hi, Ref=K6TEpccn1TbB32T8ThFsYnIl6Wm2, }} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter the user based on `Ref` attribute, I suggest you make an if-statement inside foreach loop to filter the item:

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();
        HashMap map;
        foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
        {
            //filter the user first
            map = (HashMap)item.Value;
            string userId = map.Get("Ref")?.ToString();
            if (userId!=null&& userId == user.uid)
            {
                //do what you want to do here.
            }

        }
```

Comment: In my code, i already have this `mChat =FirebaseDatabase.Instance.Reference.Child("Chat");
mChat.AddValueEventListener(this);`  meaning i am already pointing the chat.

Comment: Then, could you please use `Console.WriteLine(snapshot.ToString());` to post the log, I can't guess everything that you have coded.

Comment: And you want to select the item, which `Key=user.uid` or `Ref=user.uid`?

Comment: I want to make the query based on the current logged in user.  If you look at the Ref in log, you can see that i contains two different user id's . Hope it is clearer. So i want to return data for only the logged in user using Ref

Comment: It's best to make an if-statement to filter the user in `foreach` loop, I've modified my answer, please have a check.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ToEnumerable, the type of returned objects is DataSnapshot and it cannot be compared to user.uid. You might want to use linq to grab what you wants. something like:

*var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable(x=> x.uid == user.uid)*

Comment: this doesn't solve my issue as i still get an error saying No overload method ToEnuerable takes 1 arguement